# input to choose how many reuslts to generate

Tags: python

I have this code `for i in range(1111111111111111, 9999999999999999): print(i)`
I want to give an input which user will select how much value will the program generate.
like if he want only to generate 5k numbers it will only generate 5k.
what to do!

Comment: What have you tried? I think you missed only few things: 1. Get the user input by `input()` and 2. Check if the condition `i - 1111111111111111 > user_input` , then `break` the loop

Comment: Use `input()`: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp

Comment: I dont understand why my post got downvoted, I just want to learn! What I mean, how can i limit the results to 1000 result by example not to generate all possible results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
a = 1111
b = 9999

num = 500 # how many values you want
for i in range(a, b):
    if i >= a + num:
        break
    print(i)
```